# Creating a zip file in stream without directory structure

Tags: python, flask, zip, python-zipfile, stringio

I'm working on a Flask app to return a zip file to a user of a directory (a bunch of photos) but I don't want to include my server directory structure in the returned zip. Currently, I have this :

```
def return_zip():
    dir_to_send = '/dir/to/the/files'
    base_path = pathlib.Path(dir_to_send)
    data = io.BytesIO()
    with zipfile.ZipFile(data, mode='w') as z:
        for f_name in base_path.iterdir():
            z.write(f_name)
    data.seek(0)
    return send_file(data, mimetype='application/zip', as_attachment=True, attachment_filename='data.zip')
```

This works great for creating and returning the zip but the file includes the structure of my server i.e.

```
/dir/to/the/files/image.jpg, image1.jpg etc...
```

In the zip I just want the files, not their associated directory. How could I go about this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use the `arcname` parameter to rename the file in the zip file. We can remove the directory structure by simply passing the `write` function the name of the file you want to add, this can be accomplished as follows:

```
def return_zip():
    dir_to_send = '/dir/to/the/files'
    base_path = pathlib.Path(dir_to_send)
    data = io.BytesIO()
    with zipfile.ZipFile(data, mode='w') as z:
        for f_name in base_path.iterdir():
            z.write(f_name, arcname=f_name.name)
    data.seek(0)
    return send_file(data, mimetype='application/zip', as_attachment=True, attachment_filename='data.zip')
```

You can read more about the details of zipfile write function here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.write

Comment: That's so simple, should've read the docs :) thanks!